# Android Studios generation signed APK giving me a 28kb APK file?

Tags: android, apk

I am currently trying to create an APK of the simple android app that I made with the tutorials and then edited. However when I generate a signed APK it only gives me an APK which is 28kb big. When I attempt to install it on my nexus 7 it says 'Parse error: There was ap roblem parsing the package.' Does anyone know how to fix this :S? Thank you :). My Android version is mac 0.8.14.

Comment: Have you tried disabling proguard?

Comment: I tried disabling it via editing my 'app module' under the 'release' tab but it didn't increase the size of my release APK :S. I have a feeling it might have something to do with the app module not properly recognizing the code and contents within the folder I'm trying to turn into an APK.